# "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" when using Application.Match within VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba, function

This is my function:

```
Function stageValueVariance(stage As String, valCol As Long)
    For i = 2 To offlineHeight
        If Application.VLookup(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i).value, bce.DataBodyRange, valCol, 0) <> offline.ListColumns(valCol).Range(i).value Then
            foundID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i), oldOut.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
            If foundID = 0 Then
                foundID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i), valComp.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
            End If
            If foundID = 0 Then
                With stageValComp.ListRows.Add
                    .Range(1) = offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i)
                    .Range(2) = offline.ListColumns(2).Range(i)
                    .Range(3) = stage
                    .Range(4) = offline.ListColumns(7).Range(i)
                    .Range(5) = Application.VLookup(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i).value, bce.DataBodyRange, valCol, 0)
                    .Range(6).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Yes, No"
                End With
            End If
            foundID = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

I'm getting the 'Invalid Procedure Call or Argument' error on this line:

```
foundID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i), oldOut.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
```

If it's useful, that line of code is checking that an ID doesn't already exist within another table, so `offline` and `oldOut` are declared as ListObjects at the top of the module.

I've never come across this error before, and can't seem to find much information online. Any ideas?

Comment: I want you to debug and see the exact return value of `offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i)` I have never seen something systax as `Range(i)`

Comment: @The Gridlock you may want to create a test case and explore the unfamiliar syntax because Range(i) is almost certainly not the problem.

Comment: Thanks @profoundly , I still haven't discovered it. but maybe later :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find the `DataBodyRange` in `oldOut.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange` doesn't exist.

If testing `oldOut.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Address` returns an object not set error then this is definitely the problem.

The only way I can reproduce your error is by deleting the `DataBodyRange` or by deleting the table.  Code works fine otherwise.

Comment: OK, so a check like `If oldOut.ListRows.Count = 0 Then` could solve this?

Comment: @dhumphreys Yes.  If the table exists and the error is the result of a missing `DataBodyRange` then you can use `ListRows.Count=0`  as a test condition to trap the error.

Comment: It may be for an entirely different reason, but now that I have the code working with that check, I have a problem whereby if I step through the code, it picks up a variance and adds it to the table, but if I just run the Macro, nothing happens. Any ideas why, or shall I open another question?