# VBA Function Working when run once, but failing on successive attempts

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA function as per the below code:

```
Function stageValueVariance(stage As String, valCol As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To offlineHeight
        If Application.VLookup(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i).value, bce.DataBodyRange, valCol, 0) <> offline.ListColumns(valCol).Range(i).value Then
            If oldOut.ListRows.Count <> 0 Then
                foundID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i), oldOut.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
                If foundID <> 0 Then
                    oldOutPresent = True
                End If
            ElseIf valComp.ListRows.Count <> 0 Then
                foundID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i), valComp.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
                If foundID <> 0 Then
                    valCompPresent = True
                End If
            End If
            If oldOutPresent = False And valCompPresent = False Then
                With stageValComp.ListRows.Add
                    .Range(1) = offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i)
                    .Range(2) = offline.ListColumns(2).Range(i)
                    .Range(3) = stage
                    .Range(4) = offline.ListColumns(7).Range(i)
                    .Range(5) = Application.VLookup(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i).value, bce.DataBodyRange, valCol, 0)
                    .Range(6).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Yes, No"
                End With
            End If
            foundID = 0
            oldOutPresent = True
            valCompPresent = True
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

And am calling it in a macro using the following:

```
'find stage value variances and populate data
    Call stageValueVariance("Design", 7)
    Call stageValueVariance("Guides", 9)
    Call stageValueVariance("Lintels", 11)
    Call stageValueVariance("Install", 13)
```

The macro is searching for variances in two tables, and the `valCol` variable is specifying the column to look in. If a variance is found between `offline` and `bce` (the two tables) then a row is added to a third table - `stageValComp`.

The Function also checks that the ID of this row isn't already present in two other tables - `oldOut` and `valComp`. All variables are declared at a Public level and set in the macro that is calling this function.

The problem I'm having is when I open up the workbook and run the macro for the first time, then the code finds a variance and adds the details to `stageValComp`. For every successive attempt to run the code, the variance isn't found. If I step through the code using F8, however, the code functions correctly and finds the variance.

I've never come across this type of error before, so am a bit stumped! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Get rid of that `On Error Resume Next`... is there an error now and if so what message/what line?

Comment: BigBen, I need the `On Error Resume Next` in there, because otherwise if the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` doesn't find a match, then the code exits the function. More detail on that challenge here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685013/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-when-using-application-match-within-vba-fun

Comment: Right... but as it is right now it's hiding *all errors*, not just the potential one from `WorksheetFunction.Match`. That said, I would use the late-bound `Application.Match`, just like you are using `Application.Vlookup`.

Comment: OK, not 100% on what you're suggesting, as I can't see a way around needing `On Error Resume Next`. Do you mean I should use `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` ?

Comment: That is exactly right. Then test if the result of `Application.Match` is a number with `IsNumeric`... then you know that the match was successful. `Application.Match` doesn't throw a runtime error, unlike `WorksheetFunction.Match`.

Comment: How is using `IsNumeric` to test going to be more useful than `If FoundId <> 0`?  The latter is already working perfectly when I step through the code. Or have I missed your point?

Comment: Because `Application.Match` will return an error value if there's no match found, so you have to test if the result is a number.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` compromises *your whole function*  - any errors are silently ignored unnecessarily.

Comment: @BigBen, just tested `Application.Match` when there's no match, and it seems to return 0, so my code should catch that?

Comment: I doesn't return 0, it returns an error value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was setting `oldOutPresent` and `valCompPresent` to `True` after the If statement, when I should have been setting it back to `False` instead. The correct code (that is now working!) is:

```
Function stageValueVariance(stage As String, valCol As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To offlineHeight
        If Application.VLookup(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i).value, bce.DataBodyRange, valCol, 0) <> offline.ListColumns(valCol).Range(i).value Then
            If oldOut.ListRows.Count <> 0 Then
                foundID = Application.Match(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i), oldOut.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
                If foundID <> 0 Then
                    oldOutPresent = True
                End If
            ElseIf valComp.ListRows.Count <> 0 Then
                foundID = Application.Match(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i), valComp.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
                If foundID <> 0 Then
                    valCompPresent = True
                End If
            End If
            If oldOutPresent = False And valCompPresent = False Then
                With stageValComp.ListRows.Add
                    .Range(1) = offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i)
                    .Range(2) = offline.ListColumns(2).Range(i)
                    .Range(3) = stage
                    .Range(4) = offline.ListColumns(valCol).Range(i)
                    .Range(5) = Application.VLookup(offline.ListColumns(1).Range(i).value, bce.DataBodyRange, valCol, 0)
                    .Range(6).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Yes, No"
                End With
            End If
            foundID = 0
            oldOutPresent = False
            valCompPresent = False
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: As noted in the comments, do not use `On Error Resume Next` like this. It's a very bad idea....

Comment: Yes, noted that a few times @BigBen, do you have a suggestion for another method?

Comment: True error handling isn't a term I'm familiar with. What would I specifically change my code to?

Comment: "True" inasmuch as a blanket `On Error Resume Next` cannot be consider error handling at all... but maybe start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement).